# Is there a class like Ultimate Magus for Pathfinder?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I'm helping a friend of mine to build his character for an upcoming Pathfinder game.

We were dicussing the plausability of building something like a Sorc/Wiz Multiclass character using Ultimate Magus. However, Ultimate Magus is for 3.5 and I was unable to find such a thing for Pathfinder.

This is ***not*** an optimization question. I know that multiclassing Sorc and Wiz can be far from optimal, however optimization is not the point of this character.

If there is not such a thing like  the Ultimate Magus for Pathfinder, I would gladly accept advice on how to adapt it to a Pathfinder Game. I'm not the DM, but I'm pretty good friends with her so it would be easy to convince her to use a homebrew.

Alas, the question: is there such a class similar to the Ultimate Magus, for Pathfinder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the new Hybrid Classes in Pathfinder, the [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist) is closest to what you're looking for. I don't think the mechanics are one-to-one between the Ultimate Magus and the Arcanist, but the core idea is the same.

Hybrid Classes are meant to combine the ideas of two different classes into a single working class, and so the Arcanist combines the prepared and spontaneous spellcasting of the Sorcerer and Wizard, adding some interesting interactions and class abilities.

Comment: Not the UC magus?

Comment: The Magus is more of a Wizard/Fighter than a Wizard/Sorcerer. So I'd say that the arcanist is a better choice.